# Permission denied error while call webservice using HTTP in android application

Tags: android

I'm working in android application. I create a web service in Java. Now i want to refer a web service using HTTP. But i got `Permission Denied` error while the debugger reached the last line. The Code is:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext(); 
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://192.168.0.102:8282/SampleWebProj/services/Converter"); 
response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
```

Plz Give me a solution..

Answer (score 9):

In your code, you put

```
<uses-permission android:name="anroid.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

instead of

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

you misspelled android -> anroid != android ;-)

Comment: entirely correct. i wonder if he ever figured it out, lol. good eye btw!

Comment: this answer was edited to confusingly spell 'android' correctly, when the purposeful mispelling 'anroid' was actually the purpose of the original answer! I don't have permissions to edit the answer back

Answer (score 4):

Have you added the correct permissions on AndroidManifest.xml to open http connections?

I think, you have to add this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Yes I add permission in mainfest.xml. This is my  anroidmainfest.xml

Comment: <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="android.App" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
<activity android:name=".AndroidApp" android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>            </intent-filter></activity></application>
<uses-permission android:name="anroid.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission></manifest>

Answer (score 0):

To make use of built-in features like this in android, you must seek permission.

You need to add the permission for Internet in your AndroidManifest.xml, i.e add this line `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>`